# How do I change background image of different divs by Javascript function?

Tags: javascript, html, css

**`Here is my HTML:`**

```
<link href="styles.css" rel=stylesheet>

 <title>
 Gallery 
 </title>
</head>
 <body>
<div class="master"> 
<div class="bg1"></div>
<div class="bg2"></div>
<div class="bg3"></div>
...
```

**CSS:**

```
.bg1{
height: 100%;
background-image: url("assets/pi/file-1.jpg");
background-size: contain;
margin: auto;
background-attachment: fixed;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: center;
max-height:100%;
max-width: 100%;
}
.bg2{
height: 100%;
background-image: url("assets/pi/file-2.jpg");
background-size: contain;
margin: auto;
background-attachment: fixed;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: center;
max-height:100%;
max-width: 100%;
}
...
```

**Javascript (at the end of html before /body):**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function genBg() {

var randomNum;
var imagePath = new Array(359);  //array to hold the image filenames


for (int i=1; i<=359; i++){
    imagePath[i]= '\"assets/pi/file-'+i+'.jpg\"';// files are named as 
                                                 //'file-1, file-2..so 
                                                //this loop stores the
                                                //names in array




 randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 359);

var background = imagePath[randomNum]; // takes a random filename and 
                                       //stores it in var background

document.getElementsByClassName("bg1").style.backgroundImage ='url(\"'+background+'\")';              //changes filename


}
   </script>
```

According to this code the background of div class = "bg1" should be random but it isnt working, it is taking the default background specified in the css file. I want the function to overwrite that with a random filename

Comment: You wrote in CSS `bg1` when you should wrote `.bg1`

Comment: copy paste mistake, sorry, edited it.

Comment: [getElementsByClassName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) will return an array of objects. If you are sure it is only one than do `document.getElementsByClassName("bg1")[0].style...`, otherwise you need a loop, like [last example here](https://www.w3schools.com/JSREF/met_document_getelementsbyclassname.asp). Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace this :

```
document.getElementsByClassName("bg1")
```

by

```
 document.querySelector(".bg1")
```

and **call the function**

full code (i also corrected other errors) :

```js
function genBg() {
  var randomNum;
  var imagePath = new Array(359); //array to hold the image filenames

  for (var i = 1; i < 359; i++) {
    imagePath[i] = '"assets/pi/file-' + i + '.jpg"'; // files are named as 
   }
    //'file-1, file-2..so 
    //this loop stores the
    //names in array
    randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 359);

    var background = imagePath[randomNum]; // takes a random filename and 
    //stores it in var background
    document.querySelector(".bg1").style.backgroundImage = 'url(' + background + ')'; //changes filename
    //this line is for debug
    document.querySelector(".bg1").innerHTML = background;
  }
  genBg();
```

```css
.bg1 {
  height: 100%;
  background-image: url("assets/pi/file-1.jpg");
  background-size: contain;
  margin: auto;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  max-height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  width:200px;
  height:100px;
  border:1px solid #000;
}

.bg2 {
  height: 100%;
  background-image: url("assets/pi/file-2.jpg");
  background-size: contain;
  margin: auto;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  max-height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="master">
  <div class="bg1"></div>
  <div class="bg2"></div>
  <div class="bg3"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you it is working, can you explain the use of line  
    document.querySelector(".bg1").innerHTML = background;

Comment: the **querySelector** allow me to use CSS selector so it's easy to select the element you want. innerHTML is the content of the element, i used it only to show the url of the image. here is a link to lear more : https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_queryselector.asp